# Tube vs. Cylinder

Tags: graphics3d, regions

What is the practical difference between plotting Tubes and Cylinders?

The documentation for each describe a 3D tube/cylinder around the line between 2 points....they seem identical.

However, there is clearly a difference as I notice that

```
C1 = Cylinder[{h1, hc}, .5]
RD1 = RegionDifference[T1, C1];
```

works great, but

```
C1 = Tube[{h1, hc}, .5]
RD1 = RegionDifference[T1, C1];
```

spits back an error that Tube[...] is not a correctly specified region.

When should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are lots of places where you can indeed replace `Cylinder` by `Tube`, but `Tube` allows more styling options and flexibility. Most of this information can be collected from the documentation, so I'll just list some aspects that I think are especially noteworthy:

- In terms of regions, it seems to me that you already answered the question: you can't use `Tube` there, as the error message says.
- `Tube` supports `VertexColors` and `Cylinder` doesn't.
- `Cylinder` has a fixed radius, and `Tube` allows a variable radius so you can make non-cylindrical shapes with it.
- You can also use `Tube` with a *single* argument as a `PlotStyle` option in `ParametricPlot3D`.
- `Tube` can extend across more than two points, and even along a curve.

Answer (score 4):

You can't make worms with a cylinder ... but a Tube:

```
Graphics3D[
 Tube[BSplineCurve[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}}], .5]]
```

[image]

Tube takes a `Line` or curve to build itself around, or two endpoints. It also generates caps in a different way.

Comment: Tube may work well in the presentation world, but Cylinder with mesh is the 3D world, A good tut is some from the Blender series, I have it my self. Tough learning curve but once you learn to think 3D the rest is cake.......sort of

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/how-can-i-mesh-a-solid-cylinder-with-triangular-or-tetrahedral-elements